# Why Meteor server restarted checked for dependencies so long?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am using `meteor 1.4` and `AdamBrodzinski/meteor-react-boilerplate`.
When I modified and save code in editor. I wait for `Modified -- restarting` in console 30 - 40sec. It `checked for` all dependencies all time (even if I change one symbol). Is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly normal but this is a 'possible' behavior. When meteor restarts it does the following tasks:

1. Downloads packages. If package is already present by a new version is available, it updates that package. (But it will check for all!)
2. It compiles the packages and files and restarts 'server'  or 'only client'.

So the build times are dependent on two factors

1. The packages that you are using in your app
   and
2. The files (and the types you have changes)

Possible SolutionsSolution:

1. Try running `METEOR_PROFILE=100 meteor` to start the app. What this does is profiles the execution time of various steps. You can look under the hood to see what is happening what is taking most of the time.
2. Check for issues with `postcss`. You may read more about [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7493)

By experience, my code rebuilds usually within 2-5 secs and anything above 10s is rare. I use Macbook Air Early 2015/ 8GB model.